# How to let the user reuse a result from the previous computation in a python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, calculator

I am fairly new at python so I don't know much about it. I made a calculator and I want it to accept a:

```
ans()
```

input. Currently, there is a part that stops the program from executing an input if there is something other than [0-9 */-+] so it does not crash. How can I make

```
ans()
```

represent the output of the equation last entered so I can enter something like this:

```
>> 8*8 #last input
64 #last output
>> ans()*2 #current input
128 # current output
```

Hopefully I explained everything correctly and here is my code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
while True:
x = "x="
y = input(" >> ")
x += y
if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
    print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    continue
try:
    exec(x)
except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
else:
    print(x)
```

Update: I added several lines that were recommended in the answers but it would not run (I also fixed the indents):

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        return _
    def ans():
        try:
            return _
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        print(x)
```

Error: "Unexpected Indent" for except NameError

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use your program in the python interpreter, you can use a simple trick. The interpreter stores the last output in the special variable `_`:

```
>>> def ans():
...     return _
... 
>>> 8 * 8
64
>>> ans() * 8
512
>>> def ans():
...     return _
... 
>>> 8 * 8
64
>>> ans() * 2
128
>>>
```

Just remember, that `_` can raise a `NameError` if there hasn't been any output so far. You can handle it with something like that:

```
>>> def ans():
...     try:
...         return _
...     except NameError:
...         return 0 # appropriate value
...
```

Comment: Great, so I should put this inside of the While try right? Thanks.

Comment: @HelloWorld you can implement it in the way that you like, just remember that `_` stores the last output in the interpreter

Answer (score 1):

In the Python REPL loop _ represents the last result; however, this may not be the case in your calculator.

Try something like

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*()ans \n";
result = None
```

...

```
result = eval(x.replace('ans()',str(result))
```

You probably want something better than valid_chars though, and parse for correct expressions.  Also, as an aside, what you are evaluating are expressions not equations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This sure does help, this might even work with some of my other code. Thanks. Also, just to make sure, results go under "While True" or is it outside, just under valid_chars? And, where does the result part go? Under While True or outside. Thank you!

Comment: I would like to accept both of your answers but I can't :/

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n"
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        return z
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        z = x
        print(x)
```